# VB.NET Process BeginOutputReadLine not working

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, command-line, output, 7zip

My goal is to read output from a 7zip command line process in real time. I have coded an asynchronous output reader that uses `BeginOutputReadLine`. This method should return a new line immediately if it was send to output. Or, like MSDN says: `When asynchronous read operations start, the event handler is called each time the associated Process writes a line of text to its StandardOutput stream.`

This is my code

```
Private Sub StartProcess()
    Dim Proc As New Process

    Proc.StartInfo.FileName = Application.StartupPath & "\7z.exe"
    Proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "D:\temp"
    Proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "a -t7z ""D:\temp.7z"" -mx=9 -m0=LZMA -ms=on -mhc=on -mmt=on -mtc=off -mta=off -ptest -mhe=off"

    Proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    Proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    Proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True

    AddHandler Proc.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf OutputHandler

    Proc.Start()
    Proc.BeginOutputReadLine()
    Proc.WaitForExit()

    Proc.Dispose()
    Proc = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub OutputHandler(sendingProcess As Object, outLine As DataReceivedEventArgs)
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data) Then
        Console.WriteLine(outLine.Data)
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem is that i do not get any line until the process ends. After that all output is returned to the associated stream `OutputHandler`. The result of my asynchronous code is very much the same as using the synchronous `StandardOutput.ReadToEnd` method. What am i doing wrong?

[edit]
I have created a batch file for testing my code with a ping command. That seems to work! Does 7zip do something weird with it's output? Because it's looks like the problem has something to do with the output of 7zip rather than the code reading it.

Comment: This is entirely normal, native programs switch their stdout stream to buffered mode when it is redirected.  More efficient.  You don't see anything until the buffer is full, the program ends or the C programmer wrote an explicit fflush() call.  Which he didn't do.  Get ahead by using [SevenZipSharp](https://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/) instead.

Comment: I have tried SevenZipSharp 0.64. It looks promising but is very buggy. If you know a stable library then i would love to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove Proc.WaitForExit() from your code - it causes your application to WAIT until it ends.

If you want to know when the process has exited then use another Addhandler to catch Proc.Exited event